# Polymer and using JQuery

Tags: polymer

this is more of how does it work question than a problem.

I building a polymer app and need to use jQquery text function. So I simply call $(this.variable).text(). It all works perfectly.

When removing this script include :

I receive the below error

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Nowhere else I include jQuery. So my questions are : If another script includes jQuery does it make jQuery included in hte current app? Does Polymer never includes jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, scripts included in a web component execute in the global scope. That is to say while shadow DOM sandboxes HTML and CSS, it does not currently do that with scripts. There is some discussion of this type of isolation occurring, but it appears to be long off.

So if any web component included jQuery in the global scope - it would be available to any other web component.

While any particular polymer element COULD include jQuery, I've yet to see one that does. The Polymer library itself most certainly does not include jQuery.